# Send email to multiple recepients in apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send an email to multiple email addresses that can be found in a single cell separated by commas. I have done this before with gmail.app and it worked perfectly but I am trying to do it now using MailApp and I get an error saying the email is invalid.

```
Here is the code: 
function mail() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName("referencias");
  var mail = ss.getSheetByName("MAILS");
  var mailok = mail.getRange(1,1).getValues();
  var active_range = responses.getActiveRange();
  var cambio = responses.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 5).getValue();
  var nuevo = responses.getRange(3, 11).getValue();
  var cancelados = responses.getRange(3, 12).getValue();
  var fecha =responses.getRange(3, 8).getValue();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT+2", "dd/MM/YYYY")
  var message = {
    to: "email here",
    subject: "CAMBIOS REFERENCIAS Y DROPS: Resumen refes canceladas/añadidas",
    body:"Los siguientes modelos fueron modificados en el Master Doc ayer fecha " +date +".\n\n" + "Refes añadidas:" + nuevo + "\n\nRefes canceladas:"+ cancelados+ "\n\nCualquier consulta podéis contestar a este mail."+"\n\n Además, encontraréis adjunto un PDF con una tabla resumen de los cambios de drops."+"\n\nArchivo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d//edit#gid=1098522138",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Tabla")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

How can I send this email to many recipients at the same time? This email will be sent automatically everyday and ideally I would like it to be sent in a thread, however I have to fix this first before I try to do that.
If there is any missing information or confusion just let me know!

Comment: Try to change `to: "email here"` to `to: mailok[0][0]`

Comment: thank you! I tried with just mailok, which is what I usually do and it didn't work and i didn't think of this! thank you so much

Comment: I just tried `to: mailok[0][0]` and it works fine for me. Probably there is something wrong within your cell A1. How your cell A1 looks like?

Comment: Alternatively, instead of doing `to: mailok[0][0]`, change `mailok` line to `var mailok = mail.getRange(1,1).getValue();` and `to: mailok`. @YuriKhristich I _think_ your suggestion worked for them, but maybe the OP could clarify the last comment.

Comment: it does work now, thanks!! Adding the [0][0] to mailok fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2D array, even if the range is a single cell.
- If you want to return the value of a single cell, consider using [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) instead.

#### Solutions:

As suggested in comments, either change this line:

```
to: "email here",
```

To this one:

```
to: mailok[0][0],
```

Or, alternatively, these ones:

```
var mailok = mail.getRange(1,1).getValues();
// ...
to: "email here",
```

To these ones:

```
var mailok = mail.getRange(1,1).getValue();
// ...
to: mailok,
```